# A filtered list displayed on a new tab by date ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Excel has been out of my scope for a long time, and this feels very simple. Looking for the formula to filter a list, but the results are on a new tab.

Closest thing I have found is this [FILTER](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function) function, but as the site reads it's a new feature to be released in 2019. So I do not have access to it because I'm using Excel 2013.

I'm trying to filter on a field of Date Ranges, so all entries in the current week would be filtered to the new tab.

[image]

So filter with dates for the week of 06 Oct 2019 to 12 Oct 2019 on a new tab would return the top 2 rows only.

I have tried the FILTER function, No it doesn't work in MS Excel 2013. I also reviewed VLOOKUP, nope. I know PIVOT is not what i want. I want to avoid VBA scripting because this will go to a non-developer eventually.

Lastly filter the current table will not meet my objective.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Well I tried the filter formula above and vlookup. but those are not the results. I'm currently searching.

Comment: I have used pivot tables recently and I know  that's not the solution. I'm drawing a blank on a simple idea right now. I do not want to filter the current table because that would not complete my objective.

Comment: There might be some formula wizardry but I would use VBA for something like this

Comment: Yeah did you view the nice FILTER function that I linked to my post. It's pretty sweet. I'm seeing this as the go to response in SuperUser. Maybe I posted my message in the wrong group.

Comment: Is your goal to use formulas? Just using filter or advancedfilter can get you the results easy

Comment: @JvdV Well I want the filtered list to be contained on a new tab. On that Tab I currently have cells defined for date ranges which would be applied to that filter.

Comment: Thank you I will check out your suggestions though. I think the AdvancedFilter will help me. :)

Comment: @JvdV Trying to filter criteria of dates using AdvancedFilter - the option to filter a data range `'Sheet 1'!$B2:$B25='Sheet 2'!$D$1` is not working. Pointing it out here but searching it at the same time. I think this option might not work because I want to apply the AND operator for I want date values for a week.

Comment: I have added how to approach AdvancedFilter in my answer if you interested in how that would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Advanced Filter` will only copy to the same worksheet.

For a formula, you can create an array of relevant row numbers and return them, in order, using the `AGGREGATE` function using the `Small` function and the option to ignore errors.

Then use this to `INDEX` into the array, and `IFERROR` to take care of dragging the formula down more rows than are present.

For example, using Tables and structured references:  *In the upper right cell of where you want the results:*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1_2,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((Table1_2[[Dates]:[Dates]]>=From)*(Table1_2[[Dates]:[Dates]]<=To))*ROW(Table1_2)-ROW(Table1_2[#Headers]),ROWS($1:1)),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

Fill right and down to fill your matrix and the references should self-adjust.

*Change the `Table` to whatever your table is named, or use absolute addressing.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ron, advanced filter will pull in the results when you initiate it from the tab the data needs to be pulled into. Furthermore, good example :)

Comment: I will also attempt to use your example. Get back to you when I have this all sorted out. Thanks :) 

Also your statement about the Advanced Filter, wish I read it, just ran into this resolution.

Comment: Had to breakdown this statement piece by piece to understand it. Thank you it worked! :)

Comment: @mcv Glad it works for you.  And yes, the `FILTER` function should be easier to use, when it becomes available.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, the filter is being finicky and including a date range that falls outside the scope. I even converted the Dates to DateValue, and the value does not fall inside the scope. Keep a look out for it. :) It should be up within the hr.

Comment: Just wanted to point out one difference in this formula, In reference to my Table Column of Dates, they syntax I applied was Table[Dates].

Comment: @mcv I'll need to see an example of the Data and the formula you are using to understand the problem you are running into.

Comment: Working on it. I'm trying to resolve the issue myself first. It has to do with the Fill Down and Right. The ref to Table[Dates] Changes and it should not, and somewhere along the way I mucked up the formula. Got it fixed. :)

Comment: @mcv  Perhaps you should be using syntax:  `Table[[Dates]:[Dates]]`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld When I compared, I noted that in the first arg to INDEX I used Table[@ALL] and this was the thorn. It was displaying record that I did not want to view in the result set. The syntax you're mentioning was flagged in my initial usage for MS Excel 2013. I will review it again later. It's working and first stage of my goal is complete. Many thanks!!! :)

Comment: @mcv The syntax I show is for Fixed Addressing, so that when you drag right, it doesn't change to different columns.  Shouldn't have been flagged in any version of Excel that supports Tables, although i don't have 2013 to test.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple roads to Rome here, but let's assume this sample data on `Sheet1`:

[image]

---

***Formulas*** (just an example)

This is my result on `Sheet2`:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$10,SMALL(IF((Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10>=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1)*(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10<=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+7)=1,ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and needs to be entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down and right

---

***AdvancedFilter*** (as you seem interested in that option too)

Just to add this option (involves some manual labour though)

If you set up your second sheet like so:

[image]

Formula in `A2`:

```
=">="&TEXT(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Formula in `A3`:

```
="<="&TEXT(TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)+1,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Now, it's important to initiate `AdvancedFilter` from the sheet you want to pull data into. And assign the appropriate ranges

Result looks like:

[image]

To auto-update this `AdvancedFilter`, you need a simple piece of VBA, so paste the following as a `Worksheet_Change()` event on `Sheet1`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long

With Sheet1
    lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range("A1:C" & lr1)
End With

With Sheet2
    lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If lr2 > 3 Then
        Set rng2 = .Range("A5:C" & lr2)
        rng2.ClearContents
    End If
    rng1.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, .Range("A1:C3"), .Range("A5")
End With

End Sub
```

Now you'll be able to add data in `Sheet1` and it will auto-update the `AdvancedFilter`, which will be fast. But if you want to stay away from VBA, definately go with the formulas provided by either myself, or the more efficient approach with a ListObject by @RonRosenFeld.

---

[image]

Comment: Let me check this out. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @mcv, not a problem, since you seemed interested in AdvancedFilter, I added that option to.

Comment: Got the AdvancedFilter working, and it only works on the current page. I'm going to attempt your example above. I tried to get it to another tab, but it states only permitted to be on active tab with data. :)

Comment: @mcv, make sure to have the sheet where you want to pull data to activated when you click advanced filter

Comment: Will this Advanced Filter Update itself if the Criteria is updated? I will attempt again later. Just being sidetracked by other tasks.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't. However, a very simple piece of VBA code will do the trick. But if you want to stay away from VBA, then go with the formula's either in my answer, but more efficiently (using a listobject) as @RonRosenFeld mentioned

Comment: Nope Just tested that the Advanced Filter does not update with new values. Thank you, you are completely right. The Advanced Filter can be applied on another page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200564/discussion-between-jvdv-and-mcv).